# Using arrays in UnmanagedCallersOnly methods (C#)

Tags: c#

I'm creating a C# DLL that I'd like to run in C++. I've been using [**AOT**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/) and **UnmanagedCallersOnly** to call methods in the C# DLL from C++.

I'm hitting an issue when I need to use arrays as either return type or as a parameter type:
*Error CS8894: Cannot use 'Item[]' as a parameter type on a method attributed with 'UnmanagedCallersOnly'*

How would I go about allowing the 'GetAll' method in the below code snippet to return a dynamic array of items?

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct Item
    {
        public int Value = 0;
        // OK
        [UnmanagedCallersOnly(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(CallConvCdecl) })]
        public static Item GetSingle()
        {
            return new Item();
        }

        // Error CS8894: Cannot use 'Item[]' as a parameter type on a method attributed with 'UnmanagedCallersOnly'
        [UnmanagedCallersOnly(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(CallConvCdecl) })]
        public static Item[] GetAll()
        {
            return new Item[]{ }
        }
    }
```

I'm able to use structs and other simple value types in UnmanagedCallersOnly no problem.

From what I understand, I need to marshal the array between managed and unmanaged types. I've been doing this already with strings (via **Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi** and **Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi**) but can't seem to find any way of doing it for arrays.

Comment: Since you are only allowed to return blittable types you will run into the same issue that returning arrays has in C++ - you would have to return a pointer (such as `IntPtr`) and store the length of the array separately. And allocation would be done by something like `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`

Comment: How would I go about passing both the array pointer and its length? Ref or Out don't seem to be allowed for UnmanagedCallersOnly

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution, you can write directly to IntPtr data via Marshal.  Here's how to return an array from a C# method to C++:

```
// This assumes OutItems and OutItemNum never pass nullptr
[UnmanagedCallersOnly(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(CallConvCdecl) })]
public static void GetAll(IntPtr OutItems, IntPtr OutItemsLength)
{
    // Get items to return
    Item[] Items = new Item[]{ };
    
    // Write length
    Marshal.WriteInt32(OutItemsLength, Items.Length);
    
    // Write items
    for (int i = 0; i < Items.Length; i++)
    {
        Marshal.StructureToPtr<Item>(Items[i], OutItems + i * Marshal.SizeOf<Item>(), true);
    }
}
```

A similar process for accepting an array as a parameter:

```
[UnmanagedCallersOnly(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(CallConvCdecl) })]
public static void SetAll(IntPtr InItems, int InItemsLength)
{
    Item[] Items = new Item[InItemsLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < InItemsLength; i++)
    {
        Items[i] = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Native_User>(InItems + i * Marshal.SizeOf<Item>());
    }
}
```

Few notes (mostly for myself):

- For strings its slightly different, it looks like you need to increment the InItems offset by the string length+1)
- Big risks of memory leaks in this as I didn't investigate that at all yet, so make sure stuff gets destroyed on both the C# and C++ end